# VS Code extension - Webview view is not initialized properly

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am writing an VSCode extension and when I am triggering the "Hello" command - it seems that the webview view in not initialized properly, the the post messages are not sent and the webview view panel is not shown.

MyProvider:

```
import * as vscode from "vscode";

function getNonce() {
  let text = "";
  const possible =
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  for (let i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }
  return text;
}

const MY_COMMAND = "extension.hello";
export class MyProvider implements vscode.WebviewViewProvider {
  public static readonly viewType = MY_COMMAND;

  private _view?: vscode.WebviewView;

  constructor(private readonly _extensionUri: vscode.Uri) {}

  public postMessageToWebview(message: any) {
    console.log("$#@$@#message", message, this._view?.webview);
  }

  public resolveWebviewView(
    webviewView: vscode.WebviewView,
    context: vscode.WebviewViewResolveContext,
    _token: vscode.CancellationToken
  ) {
    this._view = webviewView; // needed so we can use it in postMessageToWebview later

    webviewView.webview.options = {
      // Allow scripts in the webview
      enableScripts: true,
      localResourceRoots: [this._extensionUri],
    };

    webviewView.webview.html = this._getHtmlForWebview(webviewView.webview);

    webviewView.webview.onDidReceiveMessage((data) => {
      console.log("message received");
      switch (data.type) {
        // other message types ...
        case "greeting": {
          console.log("HELLO!!");
          break;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  private _getHtmlForWebview(webview: vscode.Webview) {
    const styleUri = webview.asWebviewUri(
      vscode.Uri.joinPath(this._extensionUri, "src", "media", "style.css")
    );


    const actions = getActions();
    const nonce = getNonce();

    return `<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <!--
                    Use a content security policy to only allow loading images from https or from our extension directory,
                    and only allow scripts that have a specific nonce.
        -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src https: data:; style-src 'unsafe-inline' ${webview.cspSource}; script-src 'nonce-${nonce}';">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <link href="${styleUri}" rel="stylesheet">
        <script nonce="${nonce}">
            const tsvscode = acquireVsCodeApi();
        </script>
            </head>
      <body>
      The content goes here
            </body>
            </html>`;
  }
}
```

extension.ts:

```
import * as vscode from "vscode";


const MY_COMMAND = "extension.hello";

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  const provider = new MyProvider(context.extensionUri);

  context.subscriptions.push(
    vscode.commands.registerCommand(MY_COMMAND, () => {
      provider.postMessageToWebview({
        type: "greeting",
        message: "HelloWorld",
      });
    })
  );

  context.subscriptions.push(
    vscode.window.registerWebviewViewProvider(
      MyProvider.viewType,
      provider
    )
  );
}
```

This console.log is showing that the this._view?.webview is undefined
console.log("$#@$@#message", message, this._view?.webview);

The expected results is that executing the 'hello' command - it will send the message and show the console.log, show the webview view panel.